# FFMPEG/MP4BOX Muxing .mp4 with .h262, .acc x2, and srt

Tags: video, ffmpeg, converters, mp4

I'm going to attempt to re-ask this question.

What I am wanting to do, is create one new mp4 file, which will include, one video file, two audio files and one subtitle file. I am wanting to create a mp4 file that I can playback on my iOS devices and computers.
The files are as followed:

- video.h264 23.976 fps
- audioen.aac 44.1 KHz, 2, English
- audiojp.aac 48.0 KHz, 5.1, Japanese
- sub.srt

Now this srt has been converted from a mks subtitle file from a Matroska file.
I would like the English track to play by default, the Japanese track to be an option and the subtitle file to be another option.

I am having a very hard time trying to work both, mp4box and ffmpeg to create this one file, can somebody please help me with the command.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer to my question.

mp4box -add video.h264:fps=23.976 -add audioen.aac:lang=eng:name="English" -new output.mp4

I then ran

mp4box -add audiojp.aac:disable:lang=jpn:name="Japaneses" output.mp4

Please note that 'disable', after the 'audiojp.acc:' means this track will not play by default.

Subtitles however, are a nothing thing all together.